# How do I lag a data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, lag, shift

I'd like to lag whole dataframe in R.

In python, it's very easy to do this, using `shift()` function
(ex: `df.shift(1)`)

However, I could not find any as an easy and simple method as in pandas `shift()` in R.

How can I do this?

```
> x = data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(4,5,6))
> x
  a b
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6
```

What I want is,

```
> lag(x,1)
> 
  a b
1 NA NA
2 1 4
3 2 5
```

Any good idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% mutate_all(lag)

   a  b
1 NA NA
2  1  4
3  2  5
```

Comment: Do you really need `funs` on `lag`?

Comment: If OP is new to R this one might be easier to understand: `dplyr::mutate_all(x, lag)`

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted!

Comment: How can I lag 2 or 3 rows ?

Comment: `x %>% mutate_all(lag, n = 2)`

Answer (score 7):

Pretty simple in base R:

```
rbind(NA, head(x, -1))
   a  b
1 NA NA
2  1  4
3  2  5
```

`head` with -1 drops the final row and `rbind` with NA as the first argument adds a row of NAs.

---

You can also use row indexing `[`, like this

```
x[c(NA, 1:(nrow(x)-1)),]
    a  b
NA NA NA
1   1  4
2   2  5
```

This leaves an NA in the row name of the first variable, to "fix" this, you can strip the data.frame class and then reassign it:

```
data.frame(unclass(x[c(NA, 1:(nrow(x)-1)),]))
   a  b
1 NA NA
2  1  4
3  2  5
```

Here, you can use `rep` to produce the desired lags

```
data.frame(unclass(x[c(rep(NA, 2), 1:(nrow(x)-2)),]))
   a  b
1 NA NA
2 NA NA
3  1  4
```

and even put this into a function

```
myLag <- function(dat, lag) data.frame(unclass(dat[c(rep(NA, lag), 1:(nrow(dat)-lag)),]))
```

Give it a try

```
myLag(x, 2)
   a  b
1 NA NA
2 NA NA
3  1  4
```

Comment: Thank you very much for kind explanation

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness this would be analogous to how `zoo` implements it (but for a data.frame since the zoo lag(...) method doesn't work on data.frame objects):

```
lag.df <- function(x, lag) {
  if (lag < 0)
    rbind(NA, head(x, lag))
  else
    rbind(tail(x, -lag), NA)
}
```

and use like this:

```
x <- data.frame(dt=c(as.Date('2019-01-01'), as.Date('2019-01-02'), as.Date('2019-01-03')), a=c(1,2,3),b=c(4,5,6))
lag.df(x, -1)
lag.df(x, 1)
```

or you can just use zoo:

```
library(zoo)
x <- data.frame(dt=c(as.Date('2019-01-01'), as.Date('2019-01-02'), as.Date('2019-01-03')), a=c(1,2,3),b=c(4,5,6))
x.zoo <- read.zoo(x) 
lag(x.zoo, -1)
lag(x.zoo, 1)
```